# Where did Harry Potter learn that the invisibility cloak was his father's?

Tags: harry-potter, invisibility-cloak

In the Harry Potter film #2 ( The Chamber of Secrets ), there is a moment where Harry says :

> " I think it's time to use my dad's old cloak again. "

( Sorry if I misquoted by a word or two )

We only see in film #1 ( The Philosopher's Stone ) that Harry gets the cloak as a Christmas gift, but it is not explained who gave it to him or whose it was before. So I wonder, where did Harry learn that this cloak belonged to his father and who presented it to him ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The first book and film both contain the information, from a note pinned to the cloak on Christmas Morning. I cannot remember if the book quote is the same word for word but in the film Harry receives the cloak with the following note:

> Your father left this cloak in my possession before he died. It is time it was returned to you. Use it well.

The note was from Dumbledore.

[image]

ETA: I have just checked -- Dumbeldore's note is identical in the book and the film.

For completion: Dumbledore reiterates the note at the end of Philosopher's Stone:

Harry:

> And the invisibility cloak - do you know who sent it to me?

Dumbledore replies:

> Ah - your father happened to leave it in my possession, and I thought you might like it.

Comment: But actually - I think it was book seven - when Harry guesses Albus was actually analysing the cloak to discover if it was part of the Deathly Hallows. (It seems he *asked* Harry's father for the cloak, and did not "happened to leave it in my possession")

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson: "happened to leave it in my possession" is a fine example of english understatement, I think.